# How to handle incoming ajax requests after destroying window?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I create a window containing grids that send off ajax requests. Now, I immediatley close the window again before the grids are fully created and the ajax requests return.

I have two problems:

- My components within a window are still "alive" after a window is destroyed

Chrome console lists them. Although my window has the `autoDestroy: true` the gridpanel and store are still existing after the window is closed. When closed, the `destroy` event is fired. Docs say, all components under the window should be destroyed.

- Then my callbacks finally return and get executed but the window is destroyed

The problem is, that the callbacks try to reconfigure a grid that has no more store attached.

Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getCount' of null Table.js:500` (`/lib/extjs/src/view/Table.js`

How can I stop the callbacks from processing if my window is destroyed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Registering the events with **[mon](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-mon)** so that they get removed when the listening object get destroyed. Alternatively you may:

- remove them manually within the destroy() method
- check within the callback for methods or properties that may not exist to skip them

**Edit**

There are some more things that you can do

1. check if the destroy() methods of the grids get called
2. abort all request by calling **[Ext.Ajax.abortAll()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-abortAll)** (before the window close)
3. abort just specific requestst by calling **[Ext.Ajax.abort(request)](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-abort)** (before the window close)

I recommend to use option 2. because it should be the safest.

**Edit 2**

To take a look at all running request you need to look at the private `requests` property of `Ext.data.Connection` from which `Ext.Ajax` extend. `requests` is of type object and will contain a property (the request Id) for each request that is currently running.

Comment: Thanks. I have plenty of children in that main view. Is there no other way? Tried `view.removeAll()`

Comment: Thanks. The `abortAll` looks great. I will take a look at it. However I would have to know what requests are out there all the time... :/

Comment: @Indianer That is correct. But you can get a info of how many request are currently running, see my edit.